# What is the return type of internal server error response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
protected BadRequestObjectResult BadRequest()
{
    return this.BadRequest("invalid input data");
}

protected (return type?) InternalServerError() 
{
    return ?  // (what do I have to return here?);
}
```

What is the return type and what do I have to return?

Comment: `HttpStatus` code basically belongs to `enum` you can [`have a look here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=net-6.0#system-net-httpstatuscode-internalservererror). However, in your scenario you can even return as `int` as you are specifically opted to return `internal server error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are in the Controller.

```
protected IActionResult InternalServerError() 
{
    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
}
```

But that would mean you have to go to url: `/Home/InternalServerError` to get the error.

Comment: no it is not in controller ,it is in class, i am creating new custom class for response methods.this class is inherited with controllerBase and this class is inherited with controller if we want to return a status code just we call the method, so i need that internal server error method return type

Comment: Then it should be fine.

Comment: can i use ObjectResult instead of IActionResult?  @emilsteen

Comment: StatusCode() returns StatusCodeResult. StatusCodeResult and ObjectResult both inherits ActionResult, so that is the closest. BadRequest() cannot return ObjectResult either.

Answer (score 1):

Just return the internal server error code ( 500 Status )

```
return  StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
```

Comment: ok but what is the return type of the method?

Comment: @uday If only it was [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.statuscode?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Note that all these *Result objects implement `IActionResult`, so your method can just declare that.

Comment: @uday Also, if you hover over the method, Intellisense will tell you the return type.

Comment: no it is not in controller ,it is in class, i am creating new custom class for response methods.this class is inherited with controllerBase and this class is inherited with controller if we want to return a status code just we call the method, so i need that internal server error method return type @DiplomacyNotWar

Comment: @uday As I said, all of the Result objects implement `IActionResult`. This means that your method signature even for `BadRequest` can be `protected IActionResult BadRequest()` and your code will work. Likewise for `StatusCodeResult`.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest that you refer to the `IActionResult` documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iactionresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

As you can see (you may need to drill down into some of the linked types under "Derived"), all of the types such as `BadRequestResult` and `StatusCodeResult` implement `IActionResult`. Your method doesn't have to explicitly declare its signature as returning a concerete type. You can simply state that it returns `IActionResult`. For example:

```cs
protected IActionResult BadRequest()
{
    return new BadRequestResult();
}
```

Another handy place to check would be the [`ControllerBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-6.0) class documentation, which you've stated your class derives from. As you can see, there are helper methods such as [`BadRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.badrequest?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-controllerbase-badrequest), or [`StatusCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.statuscode?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-controllerbase-statuscode(system-int32)), meaning that you could actually remove the above method altogether, as you're essentially reinventing the wheel, and your derived class can simply use the existing `BadRequest` method.

If you *did* want to do something special with it (for example, returning a message), you could rewrite it like this (but you should probably give it a different name as you're currently [hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170158/c-sharp-and-method-hiding) the base method):

```cs
protected IActionResult BadRequest()
{
    return BadRequest("Down! Bad!");
}
```

Since `InternalServerError` doesn't exist, you should write your code as per [Emilsteen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73468048/3181933).

But, whatever you want to do, all the information is in the documentation.